# How to automate iframe click in selenium-ide?

Tags: selenium, iframe, ide, automation

Also, the simple click command to the skip_intro id is failing.

Comment: using which language?  you'll need to be much clearer.

Comment: Using Ruby to start with, but ultimately I would like it for JavaScript. So basically i'm trying to create a selenium script that works with / is compatible with iframe clicks. I first recorded all commands via selenium ide on Firefox, and played the test case, which played through well until it attempts to automate that command in the iframe. Hope that a little bit clearer, but please work with me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the selectFrame command in Selenium IDE to select the frame.

If your iframe is like `<iframe id="ntbanner" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="113px" frameborder="0">`

Your **command** will be **selectFrame** and the corresponding **target** will be **id=ntbanner** in IDE.

Once you are in the frame, you can click the button or elements in the frame by using normal click.  If you want to get back out of the frame you can set target as null to the selectFrame command in IDE

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I had a great feeling that it was going to work too. Based off my iframes element <iframe src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets/hub.e49de384ce9235929b9e175019bc4213.html" style="position: absolute; top: -9999em; width: 10px; height: 10px;" name="twttrHubFrameSecure" tabindex="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" id="twttrHubFrameSecure" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: With selectFrame as my command, I assumed my corresponding target would be id=twttrHubFrameSecure 

Not sure what the right target could be, i'm trying everything I could think of.

Comment: @AnthonyJones I think your target is correct. Is the command working??

Comment: Apologies for the super late response. However, Yes, after much trial and error I finally got it to work. The major breakthrough for me, was with most(if not all) elements in an iframe you have to insert the "waitForElementPresent" command above the element that the IDE is failing when executing with error"Element not found". The IDE does record and play pretty well with simple web apps, but when it comes to iframes and widgets it get a little tricky. @SudharsanSrinivasan

Comment: @AnthonyJones  Cool.  Please up vote my answer if it had helped you.

Comment: you know I tried buddy. Unfortunately, I dont have enough rep to do so.  :(